# the especific size of varbinary vs blob size

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, blob

I have a question about binary data, if I save a file in a blob column and another in a varbinary, could it be the same size? Or does the blob column have more size?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: If it's about MySQL.. [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings) all you need. The differnce is at most one byte (in theory).

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, a `BLOB` column can store up to 65,535 bytes. `VARBINARY(m)` can store up to `m` bytes, which depends on how the column is declared.

A `LONGBLOB` column has the most storage in MySQL, allowing up to 4,294,967,295 bytes.

For more specific details, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings.